# new.jar file getting downloaded automatically

Tags: downloading

What causes **new.jar** file getting downloaded frequently. I saw it happening again after deleting the downloaded new.jar file. What is this file about?

Comment: ...where is the file being downloaded to? Can you provide a list of installed applications?

Comment: @Sonickyle27 In downloads of Android phone